# How to obtain original data?

Tags: r, time-series

I am working with time series, which is not stationary. I apply the differencing and log transformation to make my data stationary.  I forecast one year ahead forecast and check the accuracy of the model by retransforming it into its original form, but fail to obtain the required result. I can explain my question with the help of a simple example:

```
    data <- c(10.45,45.6,33.67,32.12,76.34,12.3,23.5,13.76,35.78,98.45,77.88)
    ac <- diff(log(data))
    ad <- 10.45 + diffinv(exp(ac))

so ad= c(10.45000 ,14.81364, 15.55201, 16.50598, 18.88269, 19.04381, 20.95438, 21.53991, 24.14020,26.89174, 27.68280)
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to undo the `log` and the `diff` in the correct order. Also diffing is done on the log scale so adding `10.45` must be done on the log scale:

```
data <- c(10.45,45.6,33.67,32.12,76.34,12.3,23.5,13.76,35.78,98.45,77.88)
ac <- diff(log(data))
ad <- exp(diffinv(ac, xi=log(10.45)))
print(ad)
```

This yields `ad == data`.

Alternatively

```
data <- c(10.45,45.6,33.67,32.12,76.34,12.3,23.5,13.76,35.78,98.45,77.88)
ac <- diff(log(data))
ad <- exp(log(10.45) + diffinv(ac))
print(ad)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Bernhard its really works

Comment: In that case you may consider accepting the answer as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers